# layout centering not working.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am new in android and I am trying create view but there is one problem that I can't resolve it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="30dp">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_view_margin_top"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_bg">
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/loginEditText"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_edittex"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_edittex"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgetPassword"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_choose_order_type"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/layout1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_button_bg"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_choose_order_type"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/register"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_choose_order_type"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

centerHorizontal = true working fine in android version 4.0 and above but in 2.3.x it is not.I have margin=30dp but marginLeft not working in 2.3.x.  Please could you tell me what I did wrong here?

In 4 version

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58583958/Screenshot%20from%202013-11-27%2012%3A29%3A02.png

in 2.3 version

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58583958/Screenshot%20from%202013-11-27%2012%3A29%3A10.png

Comment: noo dude it will work in 2.3.x i try many times this so it is not prob may be another code has prob

Comment: Because you give match_parent in main Relative Layout remove that match_parent and use fill_parent option.

Comment: I don't get it  I run in my Nexus S and Galaxy Nexus. in Galaxy Nexus is fine but in Nexus S it's not.

Comment: fill_parent didn't help to. I tried

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot maybe? BTW, fill_parent and match_parent do exactly the same, AOSP changed the name of the flag because they deemed it clearer...

Comment: @npace see my screnshots

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinearLayout` is covering the entire width of the parent `RelativeLayout`. This means that the LinearLayout will cover the horizontal area and no space will be left to center the view horizontally.

You can try using `wrap_content` on the `LinearLayout` `android:layout_width`.

If, however, you are trying to center the view vertically (since you used `layout_height="wrap_content"`), then you should instead use `layout_centerVertical="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
i have your requirement using linear layout again let me know if any stuff
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginEditText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forgetPassword"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```